# ActionMailer in Rails 4: Cannot modify default 'from' address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

This seems to be a pretty strange issue, and after attempting to solve it from multiple standpoints, I'm a bit stuck.

Setup is fairly simple, it's just a contact form where you enter your name, email address, subject of the email, and body. This email gets sent to the host (let's call it dfnd@gmail.com) and it should be FROM the email address that the user puts in the form.

**setup_mail.rb**

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port                 => 587,
  :domain               => "gmail.com",
  :user_name            => ENV['ACTION_MAILER_NAME'],
  :password             => ENV["ACTION_MAILER_PASSWORD"],
  :authentication       => "plain",
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}

ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host] = ENV['ACTION_MAILER_HOST']
```

**notifications_mailer.rb**

```
class NotificationsMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  def new_message(message)
    @message = message
    mail(to: "dfnd@gmail.com", subject: "Contact Form: #{message.subject}")
  end

end
```

**pages_controller.rb**

```
 def create
    @message = Message.new(params[:message])

    if @message.valid?
      NotificationsMailer.new_message(@message).deliver
      redirect_to(root_path)
    else
      flash[:error] = "Please fill in the required fields appropriately."
      redirect_to contact_path
    end
  end
```

The 'from' email address that is 'stuck' in my application is **testlove@gmail.com (this is the ACTION_MAILER_NAME environment variable)**. No matter where I change the 'from' or default 'from' email address within my rails application, it is ALWAYS testlove@gmail.com.

**Even if I set the default in development.rb like so:**

```
config.action_mailer.default_options = {from: 'no-reply@example.com'}
```

the 'from' email address will still be testlove@gmail.com

What's even stranger is that if I watch my server logs, it'll show the correct email address but then when I open the actual email, it is once again ALWAYS testlove@gmail.com.

Any insight to this? I've restarted my server many a time and am pretty confused as to why this is happening.

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot do it if you use Gmail. You should use your own mail settings. Have a look at http://sendgrid.com/

Comment: That looks promising, thank you.

Comment: No problem. I have added it as an answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This cannot be done using Gmail `SMTP` settings.

You should use your own mail settings. Have a look at [Sendgrid](https://sendgrid.com/).

Comment: SendGrid is not only easy to set up, it is VERY quick. I have to say I am very impressed.

Comment: Yes. And you can use it as an add-on in Heroku.